# Can typedef structures cause name clashes when linking a static library?

Tags: c, typedef, static-linking, nm

When I create a static library, can the typedef structures cause name clashes?

Given the example header file below, I understand that `myFun()` will be an external symbol and could clash with any other library with a `myFun()` function. To avoid this, the best thing to do is give `myFun()` a longer and more specific name.

```
// myFile.h

typedef struct
{
    int myVar;
} myStruct;

void myFun(myStruct * input);
```

Is `myStruct` an external symbol that could cause naming clashes when linking with another library?

And why does it not get listed when I look at the `.a` static library file with `nm myLib.a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, names are only visible outside a library (or source file) through linkage, and in C, types do not have linkage. C11 §6.2.2/2:

> In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an entire program, each declaration of a particular identifier with external linkage denotes the same object or function.

Two `struct` definitions in different translation units (usually from inclusion of a common header) must match up to a certain degree of similarity to achieve compatibility with each other, but conceptually each translation unit has its own distinct set of data-types.

In C++, you would in theory have cause for concern, because class types, and `typedef` names declared along with a class type, do have linkage. However, in practice the linker would not see them.

So, there's really nothing to worry about.

Comment: So if I had two different version of the library linking and the myStruct was different in each then there would be an issue. By "each declaration of a particular identifier with external linkage denotes the same object or function", I assume that they should be identical?

Comment: @Markus If you link together two copies of the same library, you'll get duplicate definition errors whether or not they're the same version. "Denotes the same object or function" means there is only one of them, and it's in the library. There are no two things to be identical. This doesn't apply to types such as `struct`s. A requirement of (essentially) identical definitions does apply to `struct`s, but that is not linkage. The definition in the header you use needs to be compatible with, (essentially identical to) the definition in the header used to compile the library.